# Spring-boot JPA persisting one-to-many realation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-many

So I thought I had a simple task. My REST endpoint takes a JSON and persists it. The JSON consists of two entities: Job containing a list of events:

```
{
"job_id": 123,
"otherid": "12344B",
"myID": "asdfgasdg234234",
"country_code": "DE",
"event": [
  {
    "sometime": "2018-04-21T15:45:59.999Z",
    "some_id": 1,
    "content": {
      "product": "B5",
      "pdf_link": "https://myhost.com/pdfFile.pdf"
      }
   }]
}
```

This is being processed by:

```
@Autowired
JobRepository jobRepo;

@PostMapping("/jobs")
public Job create(@RequestBody Job job) {
    return jobRepo.save(job);
}
```

My Job class (omitted, hope I did not remove too much):

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Job extends BaseDB{

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name="Job_ID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("job_id")
    int jobID;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotNull
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "job")
    @JsonProperty("event")
    List<Event> events;
}
```

And my Event class:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Event extends BaseDB {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name="Event_No")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int eventNo;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    Job job;
}
```

The repositories are defined like this but have no logic implemented by me:

```
@Repository
public interface JobRepository extends CrudRepository<Job, Long>

@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long>
```

Now, when I send the above JSON to `/jobs` endpoint I get the following error message:
`ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage="cannot be null", propertyPath=events, rootBeanClass=class com.my.model.Job, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message`

The funny thing is, when I look into the `job` parameter that was parsed by `Jackson` in my `create()` method, I actually get a list of events with the values from the JSON. The error must be somewhere while persisting.

Did I forget something when defining `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` ?
Or is maybe my understanding of this functionality wrong and I should persist them separately? First Job and then the events?

**UPDATE**

So, after removing `job_id` from the JSON the `Job` is persisted, but the `Event` in the list is still missing.

The returned JSON looks like this:

```
{
"rowCreate": "2018-05-25T06:25:24.616+0000",
"rowModify": "2018-05-25T06:25:24.616+0000",
"rowActive": true,
"job_id": 12,
"otherid": "12344B",
"myID": "asdfgasdg234234",
"country_code": "DE",
"event": [
    {
        "rowCreate": null,
        "rowModify": null,
        "rowActive": true,
        "eventNo": 0,
        "content": "{product=B5, pdf_link=https://myhost.com/pdfFile.pdf}",
        "first": false,
        "last": false,
        "event_appearancetime": "2018-04-21T15:45:59.999+0000",
        "some_id": 1
    }
]
```

}

As you can see, the event parameters are filled with the values that should be persisted, but not all, like `rowCreate` and `rowModify`. `Job` on the other hand has those values set.

In my Eclipse terminal I see the following output:

```
Hibernate: insert into jobs (row_active, row_create, row_modify, country_code, my_id, otherid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select last_insert_id()
```

Nothing about inserting into `Event`.

To be able to work I added to my `create()` method:

```
Job newJob = jobRepo.save(job);
    List<Event> events = job.getEvents();

    for(Event event : events) {
        event.setJob(newJob);
        eventRepo.save(event);
    }
```

But is this how I'm supposed to work or should Hibernate do this in the background by itself?

Kind regards

Comment: So what's in `BaseDB`?

Comment: Where is that validation coming from? Where did you use @NotNull ?? Whats in `AuditingEntityListener`. Is there any stacktrace you can share??

Comment: BaseDB only has columns like createDate and so. I can provide it if you still think the problem could be there. NotNull is at events attribute in Job and AuditingEntityListener is as far as I know provided by spring-boot. I did not code it. I can provide a Stacktrace tomorrow.

Comment: I think `eventNo` in the `Event ` entity is going as null, `eventNo` is not coming in your JSON. Try printing the actual SQL with its parameter for debugging to know what is going null when system is trying to create data in DB.

Comment: Actually the `events` list is null. When I remove the `@NotNull` annotation it will be processed, but the JSON of the persisted object contains an event entry but with null and 0 values for the attributes. In the terminal I also only see the `Insert into Jobs` statement. Nothing for the `Events` table.

Comment: Ok, quick update: The `NotNull` exception is resolved by not adding the `job_id` in the JSON. Now the `Job` is persisted, but the `Event` still is not. I will update the question with the new issue.

Comment: Try cascade = CascadeType.ALL on List<Event> events, should work.